# Can't connect to mysql container from localhost

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a MySQL container for developing.

So I used `docker-compose` to set it up.

The container and the mysql looks OK. The thing is that I want to connect to it from a DBeaver client and I can't find how I do it.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    volumes:
       - '~/dev/dbs-data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    expose: 
      - '3306'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass'
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
       MYSQL_USER: 'user'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass'
```

When I try to connect it from `DBeaver` I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: 
"Host '172.18.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

### UPDATE

I'm not trying to connect using the IP `172.18.0.1`. I tried to connect using `localhost:3306`, `127.0.0.1:3306` and with the sub IP docker gave it `0.0.0.0:3306`

### UPDATE

After having success connecting on my Mac, I tried again with DBeaver on my linux and again:
[image]

Tried to connect with other tool, mysql workbench:
[image]

Comment: It works here. Can you connect to your MySQL server in a shell ?

Comment: @Zoyd I didn't. I never used it on terminal. Do I need to download mysql to use it on terminal?

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux host, or are you using something like Docker Machine on Windows or macOS? If you're using Docker Machine, you have to connect to the Docker Machine VM's IP address, not to `localhost`. Also, change the port mapping entry to just `3306:3306`, get rid of the `localhost` part in that...

Comment: I'm using Linux, Ubuntu.

Comment: Then change the port definition to `3306:3306` and try to connect to localhost:3306 using your MySQL client.

Comment: @nwinkler I tried this already but didn't work in my linux. I tried it right now in my mac and worked. Later, after my job, I'll try again in my linux. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @nwinkler I tried here in my linux, the same configuration I tested in my Mac. The DBeaver responds me with: `java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '172.18.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
`

Answer (score 11):

As you can see in the official image documention :

> MYSQL_ROOT_HOST : By default, MySQL creates the 'root'@'localhost' account. This account can only be connected to from inside the container, requiring the use of the docker exec command as noted under Connect to MySQL from the MySQL Command Line Client. To allow connections from other hosts, set this environment variable. As an example, the value "172.17.0.1", which is the default Docker gateway IP, will allow connections from the Docker host machine.

So you have to set the `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` variable with the address `172.18.0.1` that you can see in the error message.

Comment: Thanks! This should be accepted as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

On Docker, run this command to create a MySql container and it will expose the ports to the outside world of docker.

`docker run --name <mysql-container-name> -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<root-password>  -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<user-password> -d mysql:latest`

Few points to note:
You may see below error when trying to connect with DBeaver:

`Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Solution: When creating a new connection on DBeaver, go to `Driver Properties` look for `allowPublicKeyRetrievel` and set it to `TRUE`. Also, if needed set `useSSL` to `FALSE`.

Test your connection from DBeaver or any other clients, and it should be working.

Comment: I fixed by add option -p 3306:3306

Answer (score 0):

I am new to docker and was experiencing the same issue in Linux, it was an issue with the addresses allowed to accept connection; here is what worked out for me:

1. Find the MySql configuration file named **mysqld.cnf**

   It would be: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
   Or if you have your own configuration file.
2. Edit the **bind-address** key in it.
    Set it as:
    `bind-address  = 0.0.0.0`
3. This will allow to accept connections from any IP address 
   Restart docker-compose by
    **$** `docker-compose down`
   **$** `docker-compose up`
4. Wait for MySQL to start, it should work fine now.